# How to read matrix and sum them up?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, sum

I wanted to do a coding where it reads a 4x4 matrices and sum them up. I dont know where I did wrong. My result is it keeps on asking to enter the elements. I just wanted a 4x4. Can anyone help me?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


const int SIZE = 4;
double sumColumn(const double m[][SIZE], int rowSize, int columnIndex)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<SIZE; j++)
        {

            sum = sum + m[i][j];
        }

    }
    return sum;
}
int main()
{
    double m[SIZE][SIZE], sum = 0;
    cout << "Enter the elements of the matrix" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j<SIZE; j++)
            cin >> m[i][j];


    sum = sumColumn(m, SIZE, SIZE);

    cout << sum << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you get the `"Enter the elements of the matrix"` message all the time?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A good practice is using curly braces even if the content of the "for" has one line, but in your case must be in the next way

```
for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<SIZE; j++) {
        cin >> m[i][j];
        sum = sumColumn(m, SIZE, SIZE);
    }
}
```

Greetings

The complete code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 4;
double sumColumn(const double m[][SIZE], int rowSize, int columnIndex)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<SIZE; j++)
        {
            sum = sum + m[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
int main()
{
    double m[SIZE][SIZE], sum = 0;
    cout << "Enter the elements of the matrix" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<SIZE; j++) 
        {
            cin >> m[i][j];
            sum = sumColumn(m, SIZE, SIZE);
        }
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Putting the summation function call there would lead to undefined behavior, as it would be called with a partially uninitialized array.

Comment: Thank you so much mate. Thank you. god bless you. you are a life savior. :')